# runtime error while submitting code in uva using python

Tags: python-3.x

this is my code for problem no 623 (500!)

```
def fact(n):
    ans=1;
    for i in range (1,n+1):
        ans=ans*i;
    return ans;

while(True):
    n=input()
    if not n:
        break
    n=int(n)
    print (str(n)+"!")
    print (fact(n))
```

it gives runtime error in uva verdict but runs fine on pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` is causing an EOFError. Do

```
try:
    n=input()
except EOFError:
    break
```

instead of

```
n=input()
if not n:
    break
```